# Permissions on solution files to modify

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, project-conversion

I have project solutions developed in VS2005. It is bound to TFS (Team Foundation Server). I want to convert the solution to VS2008 version, keeping the binding as is, however I am getting an error while converting.

Error message:

> Solution file "*C:\abc\abc.sln*" cannot be converted because it cannot be modified. To convert the solution, change the permissions on the solution file to allow modification and reopen it"

What permissions do I need on this?

Answer (score 30):

Make sure the sln solution file is not marked as **read only**.

Answer (score 6):

If I correctly interpret your question, you should check if your current Windows account has the **NTFS (file system) permission to modify** the solution file (.sln). Check the security settings in Windows Explorer right clicking on that file to ensure that you have write access to it.

I would also check if the file is **not write protected** (checkbox on file properties in Windows Explorer).