# Migration issue in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open visual studio 2010 project in vs2012 and it tries to migrate it to 2012

Getting this error:

Solution file 'D:....\project1.sln' cannot be migrated because it cannot be modified. To migrate the solution, change the permissions on the solution file to allow modification and re-open it.

Comment: To migrate the solution, change the permissions on the solution file to allow modification and re-open it.

Comment: Use the Windows Explorer, right click and choose Properties. The Property Dialog has a read-only check box. Uncheck.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. you saved the day.

Comment: @RHM Do you run VS in administrative mode. If not then make sure your current user is permitted to explore (create and edit) the files or files are not in readonly mode.

Comment: @manuell You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Actually looks like this question was previously asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385874/permissions-on-solution-files-to-modify